# ffplay, how to use a dshow device + a filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying this:

```
ffplay -fs -f dshow "amovie='virtual-audio-capturer'[aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1366x768:volume=30[out0]"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[dshow @ 03d62b80] Malformed dshow input string.B sq=    0B f=0/0
amovie='virtual-audio-capturer'[aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1366x768:volume=30[out0]: I/O error
```

This works though, but it's not exactly what I want:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" yo.ogg
```

And this works, need to do those two without an extra step of this `yo.ogg` file:

```
ffplay -fs -f lavfi "amovie='yo.ogg'[aud];[aud]asplit[aud][out1];[aud]showcqt=1366x768:volume=30[out0]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie='audio\=virtual-audio-capturer':f=dshow,showcqt=1366x768:volume=30"
```

You don't want an echo of the audio already playing, so I've muted the audio output from ffplay.

I get a large latency on the showcqt output, so it's better to use ffmpeg for this:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -filter_complex "showcqt=1366x768:volume=30" -f sdl2 -
```